# Bat file to open screens and execute commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have three bat files that run in 3 cmd screens.

**mongod.bat**

```
C:\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath C:\mongodb\data
```

**start.bat**

```
cd C:\www\project
npm start
```

**runGulp.bat**

```
cd C:\www\project
npm run gulp
```

How do I run these three files with a 4 file executing them, opening the cmd 3 screens?

I tried with the file below but it only open the screen of the file mongod.bat

**desenv.bat**

```
call mongod.bat
call start.bat
call runGulp.bat
```

Comment: Try start /c instead of call

Comment: Thank you work replace `call` by `start`, as a `/c` not work

Comment: Makes sense. Good work reporting back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
 @echo off
 start cmd "call ex1.bat&ex2.bat&ex3.bat"
```

Comment: Run the first program using the start command.
Check the task list in a loop to see if the program has appeared there.
Impose some time limitation to the said loop.
Run the next program in case of success, exit with notification otherwise.
The scripting might look like this:

@ECHO OFF
START program1.exe
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,100) DO (
  (TASKLIST | FIND /I "program.exe") && GOTO :startnext

  :: you might add here some delaying
)
ECHO Timeout waiting for program1.exe to start
GOTO :EOF

:startnext
program2.exe
:: or START program2.exe